# How to define a subdomain URL rewrite rule for more complex URL

Tags: url, for-loop, url-rewriting, rule

how to create rewrite rule for that url like

http://www.abc.in/subfoldername/index.php?alist&TP=xyz&ct=bcd

to

http://bcd.abc.in

Answer (score 0):

Enter this following code to **.htaccess**:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([a-z0-9_-]+)\.(.+)$
RewriteRule ^$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/subfoldername/index.php?alist&TP=xyz&ct=%2 [L]
```